I am unable to display amount in terms of lakhs in Excel
I am unable to display ammunts/ numbers in Lakhs format in Excel 2019 under Windows 11. I have tried every available option the regional settings to point towards English (India), Digit Format as 12,34,56,789 format too
But still it doesn't work and display the numbers in millions format

Use the following custom number format. You can replace Tk. with Inr or Rp.
[>=10000000] ##\,##\,##\,##0.00 "Tk.";[>=100000]##\,##\,##0.00 "Tk.";##,##0.00 "Tk."

If you do not need Tk. and decimal places then use-
[>=10000000] ##\,##\,##\,##0;[>=100000]##\,##\,##0;##,##0


